UNIQUE constraint failed when I insert "10" when "1" exists
I create a table first:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS image_table ("name" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "data" BLOB) WITHOUT ROWID;

Then I prepare the insert statement:
    const char insert_statement[] = R"(
        INSERT INTO image_table (name, data) VALUES (?1, ?2);
)";


    sqlite3_stmt* insert_row_statement;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_statement, sizeof(statement), &insert_row_statement, nullptr);

Now I loop and I insert use "name" + i as the key name to insert a new row:
const char blob_data[] = "This is blob data yada yada yada";


    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
    {
        std::string key_name = std::string("name").append(std::to_string(i)).c_str();
        auto key_size = key_name.size();
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert_row_statement, 1, key_name.data(), key_name.size(), nullptr);
        sqlite3_bind_blob(insert_row_statement, 2, blob_data, sizeof(blob_data), nullptr);
}

So that the key name is "name0" and then "name1" and then "name2" etc. The problem is that I get an error issued when it gets to "name10". This doesn't make sense as "name10" is different from any other name. I ensured that the size that I pass to the bind function is 6 for (n-a-m-e-1-0), as you can see in the code. But I still get this error. Is this is a SQLite quirk?
Here is a MRVC that can be run:
//#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    sqlite3* db;

    if (sqlite3_open("D:/images.db", &db) != SQLITE_OK)
        return 0;

    /* CREATE SQL STATEMENT */
    const char statement[] = R"(
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS image_table ("name" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, "data" BLOB) WITHOUT ROWID;
)";

    constexpr auto sizeofstatement = sizeof(statement);
    sqlite3_stmt* create_table_statement;
    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, statement, /* LEN OF STRING */ sizeof(statement), &create_table_statement, nullptr);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) std::cout << "Failed to compile SQL statement";


    /* EXECUTE STATEMENT, CREATE TABLE */
    result = sqlite3_step(create_table_statement);

    if (!(result == SQLITE_OK || result == SQLITE_DONE))
    {
        std::cout << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
        return 0;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(create_table_statement);







    const char insert_statement[] = R"(
        INSERT INTO image_table (name, data) VALUES (?1, ?2);
)";
    sqlite3_stmt* insert_row_statement;
    result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_statement, sizeof(insert_statement), &insert_row_statement, nullptr);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        std::cout << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
        return 0;
        int a = 3;
    }


    const char blob_data[] = "This is blob data yada yada yada";


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        std::string key_name = std::string("name").append(std::to_string(i)).c_str();
        auto key_size = key_name.size();
        result = sqlite3_bind_text(insert_row_statement, 1, key_name.data(), key_name.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);// IF STATIC IS CHANGED TO TRANSIENT THEN THE UNIQUE CONSTRAINT ERROR OCCURS WHEN i IS 1
        // AND KEY NAME IS "name1".
        result = sqlite3_bind_blob(insert_row_statement, 2, blob_data, sizeof(blob_data), SQLITE_STATIC);




        result = sqlite3_step(insert_row_statement);


        if (!(result == SQLITE_OK || result == SQLITE_DONE))
        {// UNIQUE constraint error occurs here on inserting key "name10"
            std::cout << "Error occurred, key_name: " << key_name << "\n";
            std::cout << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << "\n";

            
        }
    }


    //throw;
    sqlite3_finalize(insert_row_statement);





}


Why are you inserting strings into a column given an integer affinity? Sqlite will let you do that on non-strict tables, sure, but it's confusing.

@Shawn What's the process? The affinity is integer if you give it a string it will attempt to convert the string to integer and store as an integer. If not it stores a string? Is it like Python or Javascript where the type that's stored keeps an id or flag or something of what type it is? Everything is dynamic?

@Shawn That was a mistake, I changed it to name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, but it still does the same thing, ie., complains that UNIQUE constraint not met when I try to insert key "name10".

@Zebrafish Datatypes in SQLite covers how type affinity works.

sqlite3_bind_text(insert_row_statement, 1, key_name.data(), key_name.size(), nullptr);

The last argument to the text and blob binding functions is defined to take one of three different things:

A destructor to dispose of the BLOB or string after SQLite has finished with it may be passed.
The special constant, SQLITE_STATIC, may be passed to indicate that the application remains responsible for disposing of the object. In this case, the object and the provided pointer to it must remain valid until either the prepared statement is finalized or the same SQL parameter is bound to something else, whichever occurs sooner.
The constant, SQLITE_TRANSIENT, may be passed to indicate that the object is to be copied prior to the return from sqlite3_bind_*(). The object and pointer to it must remain valid until then. SQLite will then manage the lifetime of its private copy.

A null pointer is not a valid value to pass to it, but that's what you're providing. Naturally weird stuff can happen if you don't follow the rules the function works under. In this particular case, since SQLITE_STATIC is defined as ((sqlite3_destructor_type)0), that's what it thinks you're giving it.
You only included a fragment of your code, with no sqlite3_step() or anything to show how you're using the prepared statement, but you're presumably doing something that violates the requirements of using SQLITE_STATIC. Passing SQLITE_TRANSIENT is the safer option here.
For the blob_data binding, SQLITE_STATIC does look like it's appropriate. Use that value instead of nullptr for those parameters.

Turns out you need "sqlite3_reset(/* the statement */);" before binding the new text, it was using old string length.

OK the problem is that in a loop like this:
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{

    sqlite3_bind_text(insert_row_statement, 1, key_name.data(), key_size, SQLITE_STATIC);
    




    sqlite3_step(insert_row_statement);


    

}

You have to call:
sqlite3_reset(/* the statement */);

Before calling bind text again. It turns out it was using the string length from the previous bind test.
